# Nvim keeps taking my terminals transparency off

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm using the Windows Terminal thats available on the Microsoft Store (not the default), and I currently have acrylic and transparency on it. However everytime I open nvim, the colorscheme I have colors the background and the transparency goes away. I tried a couple solutions:

```
highlight Normal ctermbg=NONE
set t_Co=256
set termguicolors
let $NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_TRUE_COLOR=1
colorscheme solarized8_flat
highlight Comment cterm=italic gui=italic
if &term =~ '256color'
  " disable Background Color Erase (BCE) so that color schemes
  " render properly when inside 256-color tmux and GNU screen.
  set t_ut=
endif
```

None of this works or changes anything, the window where the nvim background is not transparent.
Is there any way to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you move the `highlight`  statement after `colorscheme solarized8_flat`?